# Compiling custom package for Linux Embedded Development Environment (LEDE) (same as OpenWRT)

Tags: c, linux, router, openwrt, firmware

`Hi all,`

Platform: x86_64

I successfully installed a Linux Embedded Development Environment (LEDE) x86/64 (same as OpenWRT) to my virtual machine.

I developed a custom package "Hello World" for Linux Embedded Development Environment (LEDE) with SDK and cross-compiled it . Then, tested it on my virtual machine and it worked.
But, then I have my own code to port that is, for raw packet sniffer in c and I want to port that code. So, I copied same code under that same file that I used for "Hello world" (helloworld.c). Again, I successfully cross-compiled new binary "*.ipk format" then send it on my LEDE virtual machine and did `opkg install xxxxxx.ipk`. It installed, but same output. I mean "Hello world".

I don't know how. Because, code changed this time. Then, again for testing a wrote a simple factorial code and again . During testing in virtual machine. I found that it didn't work because same output again that is, "Hello world".

Documentation:[Hello world package for LEDE using LEDE Source](https://lede-project.org/docs/guide-developer/helloworld/start)
I am developing using SDK instead of source.I followed every thing in Documentation excluding source compiling and all.

Documentation for SDK: [Compile custom package using SDK](https://lede-project.org/docs/guide-developer/compile_packages_for_lede_with_the_sdk)

Makefile for Hello World code:

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk

# Name, version and release number
# The name and version of your package are used to define the variable to point to the build directory of your package: $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
PKG_NAME:=helloworld
PKG_VERSION:=1.0
PKG_RELEASE:=1

# Source settings (i.e. where to find the source codes)
# This is a custom variable, used below
SOURCE_DIR:=/home/buildbot/helloworld

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk

# Package definition; instructs on how and where our package will appear in the overall configuration menu ('make menuconfig')
define Package/helloworld
  SECTION:=examples
  CATEGORY:=Examples
  TITLE:=Hello, World!
endef

# Package description; a more verbose description on what our package does
define Package/helloworld/description
  A simple "Hello, world!" -application.
endef

# Package preparation instructions; create the build directory and copy the source code. 
# The last command is necessary to ensure our preparation instructions remain compatible with the patching system.
define Build/Prepare
        mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
        cp $(SOURCE_DIR)/* $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
        $(Build/Patch)
endef

# Package build instructions; invoke the target-specific compiler to first compile the source file, and then to link the file into the final executable
define Build/Compile
        $(TARGET_CC) $(TARGET_CFLAGS) -o $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/helloworld.o -c $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/helloworld.c
        $(TARGET_CC) $(TARGET_LDFLAGS) -o $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/$1 $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/helloworld.o
endef

# Package install instructions; create a directory inside the package to hold our executable, and then copy the executable we built previously into the folder
define Package/helloworld/install
        $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/usr/bin
        $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/helloworld $(1)/usr/bin
endef

# This command is always the last, it uses the definitions and variables we give above in order to get the job done
$(eval $(call BuildPackage,helloworld))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cross-compiled the same code again and tested it with `LinkIt Smart 7688` and everything is working as expected. So, I think something went wrong with that LEDE Virtual Machine that I created for testing.

> ***LinkIt Smart 7688:***
> It is an open development board which is based on OpenWrt Linux distribution and MT7688.
> The platform also offers options to create device applications in
> Python, Node.js and C programming language.
>
> So, I think It is one of the best board available for IoT things within 12.90 US  Dollars.

Answer (score 0):

I added custom package in openwrt successfully and this is my Makefile, hope this helps you

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk

PKG_NAME:=viva
PKG_VERSION:=1.4
PKG_RELEASE=$(PKG_SOURCE_VERSION)
PKG_MAINTAINER:=Vishal <yourname@domain.for.your.name>
PKG_LICENSE:=ISC

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk

define Package/viva/default
  CATEGORY:=Network
  SUBMENU:=Web Servers/Proxies
  TITLE:=Webpage for package creation
endef

define Package/viva
  $(Package/viva/default)
  DEPENDS:=+uhttpd
endef

define Package/viva/description
    A web page used for illustrating package creation
endef

define Package/viva/install
    $(CP) ./files/* $(1)/
endef

define Build/Compile
    true
endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage,viva))
```

Comment: Thanks, It seems simple and easy to understand. But, In my case, I had issue with Virtual machine in which I installed OpenWRT based firmware named LEDE (The LEDE Project (“Linux Embedded Development Environment” [link](https://lede-project.org/)) is a Linux operating system based on OpenWrt) . Still I don't know about the issue that why this happened.

Comment: Because I unpacked the `*.ipk` package using zcat and searched for `hello world` keyword, but there was nothing at the time when binary is in my cross complation machine,then, I sent it using scp to target openwrt virtual machine, then there I installed with `opkg install helloworld*.ipk` then again during execution it prints "Hello world".So, this, time I again unpacked it and searched for "Hello world",then I found there a Hello world string. I still don't know from where that come.